# Python Turtle Graphics Choose Point X Distance Away

Tags: python, random, turtle-graphics

I am writing a program for the Python Turtle module and I would like it to choose a position X distance away. So basically, from the turtle's present position it needs to choose a point no further or less than X distance away and have the ability to draw a line to that position. Additionally, it should chose this position at random so it is different almost every time.I know I should use the Pythagorean theorem and perhaps the randint module, but I can't figure out how to implement either.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Cheers!
5813

Comment: Have you tried anything? where is your code?

Comment: You don't need to choose a position per se, you just have to turn the turtle a random amount left or right (doesn't matter which) and move it forward X steps.

Comment: I should add, this actually is choosing a position... using polar coordinates.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say in this case, you want x to be 50

```
import turtle
from random import randint

x = 50

turtle = turtle.Turtle()

degrees = randint(0, 360)
turtle.left(degrees)
turtle.forward(x)

turtle.getscreen()._root.mainloop()
```